# How to integrate the latest admob sdk to Android app

Tags: android, mobile, admob, ads

I have an app in the store which has Admob. But now I want to update the Admob sdk just to be up-to-date

I was reading that. Now we do not need to install the sdk from Admob site. As it is already included with Android sdk.

Is that correct. What shall I do now.... Is there any link or tutorial for that.

Answer (score 0):

The Admob libraries are now part of Google Play Services.
You need to include Play Services.

You can find the latest version of the Admob libraries by looking in

`ANDROID-SDK_HOME\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services-ads`.

As of 9-AUG-2015 it is 7.5.0

Comment: Do you know what is the latest version number